How to get an svg in-line with text in typst?
This is most likely a bad idea but I want to use custom SVGs and make them small enough that they show up in line with text.
So far I have the following code
[#image(entry.Logo, height: 1em, width: 1em, fit: "contain") #h(0.5cm) This is what I wanted to show ] 
but the SVG keeps taking up a whole line as shown in the attached image.
The svg render just fine despite the small size - I am wondering if there is something I am missing syntax wise to make it happen.


make the image display: inline;

@RobertLongson I was not able to find either display param for image or inline function in typst documentation https://typst.app/docs/reference/visualize/image/. Probably looking in the wrong place but box solved my issue for now.

This was the syntax that solved my issue
box(image(path to file),height:1em)
text

